# Load GPS tracking data from web site into QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there any possibility to import GPS tracking data from this site - https://lifeneophron.eu/#transmitters into QGIS?

It would work for me if I took a screenshot of the map and georeferenced it, but it would be better if I had a vector layer.

Answer (score 2):

I think its possible, but not trivial, and there may be a better way.

When you select one of the vultures in the drop-down menu to see its tracking info, a URL is called to get the data which is then displayed on the map. The URL is of the form:

https://lifeneophron.eu/back2/public/api/movebank/current-vulture-ex/54/2592000

which returns data in a series of JSON data like this:

```
 {
    "move_bank_id": 54,
    "lng": 25.93133,
    "lat": 41.6535,
    "time": 1377684000,
    "s": -1
  },
  {
    "move_bank_id": 54,
    "lng": 25.91967,
    "lat": 41.65233,
    "time": 1377676800,
    "s": -1
  },
```

Then isn't a standard geospatial data format so a little conversion would be needed to read into QGIS.

Now, I'm not sure what the "2592000" is in the URL, but if I increase it I get more data back, so I suspect it means "return records in the last 2592000 seconds" (exactly 30 days). If you put a 0 on the URL instead you get a lot more records back for bird 53 for example.

From the URL it looks like they are using "movebank", which is a private server storing animal movement data, which researchers can use to release data publicly (https://www.movebank.org) but I can't see it there. I can see there's a "Life Egyptian Vulture" project that ended in 2021 and it looks like you are interested in "NEW Life" which I guess is a followup project. I can't see that on MoveBank but maybe the name is different and its one of the other Egyptian vulture projects listed there. If it is and the data is public then that might be the best place to get it.

Otherwise, the URLs in the project web site look like they are part of their web content system and their server possibly calls the movebank API to get the data. For example, to get the study data on individuals get:

https://lifeneophron.eu/back2/public/api/movebank/public-data-ex/1

which returns JSON data with a structure for each individual (ID, name, status etc). From that you can get all the ID values and then get all the tracking data via the `current-vulture-ex` URLs. This could all then be put together into a geopackage to read into QGIS using something like a Python script.

This kind of data scraping isn't the most polite way of getting data, you should always try and contact the authors - they may show you a better way of getting the data and let you know any restrictions or terms-of-use you need to comply with.